# Counting positive words in a passage python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, return

I have to count the times positive and negative words appear in a passage.

I have a list of positive words, list of negative words, and a passage excerpt.

```
pos_words = ['happy', 'like', 'love', 'good', 'favorite', 'best', 'great', 'amazing', 'joyful', 'positive']
neg_words = ['sad', 'dislike', 'hate', 'angry', 'horrible', 'bad', 'worst', 'boring', 'negative']
passage_excerpt = "I love CSS 1, it's my favorite class and not as horrible as I thought"
```

I have to return a dictionary titled sentiment_info that looks like this:

```
{'num_pos_words': ..., # how many positive words
 'num_neg_words': ..., # how many negative words
 'num_words_total': ... # how many total words
```

I have tried this code so far:

```
def calculate_words(x):
    cleaned_passage = clean_text(x)
    num_pos_words = 0 
    num_neg_words = 0 
    num_words_total = 0 
    if x in pos_words and passage_excerpt:
        num_pos_words += 1 
    if x in neg_words and passage_excerpt: 
        num_neg_words += 1 
    num_words_total = num_pos_words + num_neg_words

    return{'num_pos_words': num_pos_words,
     'num_neg_words': num_neg_words,
     'num_words_total': num_words_total}
```

I do not know if a function was the correct approach or I needed a for loop.

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Comment: `if x in pos_words and passage_excerpt` This is not doing what you think.

Comment: What is `x` supposed to be?  You haven't shown us how this function is called.

Comment: What is the ```clean_text()``` supposed to do?  can you show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I little modification in your code:

```
def calculate_words(y):
    num_pos_words = 0 
    num_neg_words = 0 
    num_words_total = 0 
    for x in y.split(): # ['I', 'love', 'CSS', '1,', "it's", 'my', 'favorite', 'class', 'and', 'not', 'as', 'horrible', 'as', 'I', 'thought']
     if x in pos_words and x in passage_excerpt:
        num_pos_words += 1 
     if x in neg_words and x in passage_excerpt: 
        num_neg_words += 1 
    num_words_total = num_pos_words + num_neg_words

    return{'num_pos_words': num_pos_words,
     'num_neg_words': num_neg_words,
     'num_words_total': num_words_total}


print(calculate_words(passage_excerpt))
#{'num_pos_words': 2, 'num_neg_words': 1, 'num_words_total': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `calculate_words`? And yes, you need to **loop** through the words [which you can use [`.split`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/split) to get], but that does not preclude using a function. I think your intended purposes can be served with something like

```py
def calculate_words(x, pList=['good'], nList=['bad']):
    x_words = x.split() ## without cleaning
    # x_words = clean_text(x).split() ## words after cleaning
    num_pos_words, num_neg_words = 0, 0
    for w in x_words:
        if w in pList: num_pos_words += 1
        elif w in nList: num_neg_words += 1

    num_words_total = num_pos_words + num_neg_words # only count if +ve or -ve
    # num_words_total = len(x_words) # count ALL words

    return {  'num_pos_words': num_pos_words,
              'num_neg_words': num_neg_words,
              'num_words_total': num_words_total  }

passage_word_counts = calculate_words(passage_excerpt, pos_words, neg_words)
```

then `passage_word_counts` would return

> ```py
> {'num_pos_words': 2, 'num_neg_words': 1, 'num_words_total': 3}
> ```

Although, if you used `num_words_total = len(x_words)` then `passage_word_counts` would return

> ```py
> {'num_pos_words': 2, 'num_neg_words': 1, 'num_words_total': 15}
> ```

---

Btw, the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) is quite handy for this sort of thing.

```py
import collections

# passage_words = clean_text(passage_excerpt).split() 
passage_words = passage_excerpt.split()
passage_word_counts = {**collections.Counter(
    'num_pos_words' if w in pos_words else (
        'num_neg_words' if w in neg_words else 'num_na_words'
    ) for w in passage_excerpt.split()
), 'num_words_total': len(passage_words)}
```

> ```py
> # passage_word_counts = \
> {'num_na_words': 12,
>  'num_pos_words': 2,
>  'num_neg_words': 1,
>  'num_words_total': 15}
> ```

or

```py
import collections

# passage_words = clean_text(passage_excerpt).split() 
passage_words = passage_excerpt.split()
passage_word_counts = collections.Counter((
    'num_pos_words' if w in pos_words else 'num_neg_words'    
) for w in passage_excerpt.split() if w in pos_words+neg_words)
passage_word_counts['num_words_total'] = sum(passage_word_counts.values())
```

> ```py
> # passage_word_counts = \
> {'num_pos_words': 2, 'num_neg_words': 1, 'num_words_total': 3}
> ```

Answer (score -1):

you can use sum() with a condition in a comprehension to count matching words (True counts as 1 and False as zero):

```
words = passage_excerpt.split()
D = {'num_pos_words': sum(word in pos_words for word in words),
     'num_neg_words': sum(word in neg_words for word in words),
     'num_words_total': len(words) }


{'num_pos_words': 2, 'num_neg_words': 1, 'num_words_total': 15}
```